# MKMapView fit annotations in a subrect of mapView visible rect

Tags: ios, annotations, mkmapview, frame, pins

I've a view with a `MKMapView` with the same size of `self.view.bound` but it's completely visible when "closed" (a part of the map is hidden but already drawn).

I'd like to fit all of the annotations pins to the visible rect, but without any pins at border. So what I want to do is to fit all of the annotations to a sub-rect of the visible (that is a subrect of the `mapView`) when the map is closed.

And when the map is open (completely visible) to fit the annotations pins to the whole rect. This will give a zoom effect, too.

I know how can get the `MKMapRect` (or `Region`) for all pins but no how to fit that `MKMapRect` (/`Region`) to a desired sub-rect of the map rect...
Can you help me please?

here's what I've done

```
- (void) fitMapForAnnotationsAnimated:(BOOL)animated{

if ([self.mapView.annotations count]<=1) return;

MKMapRect mapRect = MKMapRectNull;

for(id<MKAnnotation> annotation in [self.mapView annotations]){

    if (![annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
        MKMapPoint annotationPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate([annotation coordinate]);
        MKMapRect pointRect = MKMapRectMake(annotationPoint.x, annotationPoint.y, 0.1, 0.1);
        mapRect = MKMapRectUnion(mapRect, pointRect);
    }

}

MKMapRect newMapRect = mapRect;

if (mapFullScreen) {

    newMapRect =  [self.mapView mapRectThatFits:mapRect edgePadding:UIEdgeInsetsZero];


}else{

    MKMapView *smallMap = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.homeViewController.tableView.tableHeaderView.frame];

    newMapRect = [smallMap mapRectThatFits:mapRect edgePadding:UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 5, 5, 5)];

    smallMap = nil;
}

MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(newMapRect);
MKCoordinateRegion fitRegion = [self.mapView regionThatFits:region];

[self.mapView setRegion:fitRegion animated:animated];
```

}

When the map is full screen the fitRegion center is in the lower part of self.mapView and not at center, even If I set it manually.

Comment: If you have an MKMapRect, have you tried using the setVisibleMapRect:edgePadding:animated: method?

Comment: Yes but some of the pins are hidden in the lower part. the mapView is attached (programmatically) at UITableView.headerView so the higher part is hidden and with origin.y negative. here's what I use  [self.mapView setVisibleMapRect:mapRect edgePadding:UIEdgeInsetsMake(abs(CGRectGetMinY(self.mapView.frame)), 5, 5, 5) animated:YES];

Comment: If i setVisibleMapRect for open mapView and then for the close mapView the visible annotation and region is different from the start state (close map)